# How to output the sorted deadlines with the matching subject?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, sorting, arraylist

I am making a program which allows a user to input how many pieces of homework they have, the subject, the actual homework and the deadlines. Then I want to sort the deadlines in ascending order so the shortest deadline comes first. The I want to output the sorted deadlines with the correct subject and homework however, I don't know how to do this.

I have already ordered the deadlines and used a for loop to allow the user to enter all their homeworks.

```
  Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my homework organiser. How many pieces of homework do you have?")

    repeats = Console.ReadLine()

    For i = 0 To repeats - 1
        Console.WriteLine("Enter subject " & i + 1)
        subject.Add(Console.ReadLine())
        Console.WriteLine("Enter homework " & i + 1)
        homework.Add(Console.ReadLine())
        Console.WriteLine("how many days until " & subject(i) & "'s homework is due?")
        deadline.Add(Console.ReadLine())
    Next

    deadline.Sort()

    For counter = 0 To deadline.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine(subject.Item(counter) & ", " & homework.Item(counter) & ", " & deadline.Item(counter) & " days")
    Next
```

Comment: I suggest you use a class for this.

Comment: thanks for the reply, how do you suggest I use a class?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using classes and [List.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2) function.

Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

```
Public Class Homework
    Public Subject As String
    Public Text As String
    Public Deadline As Integer
End Class

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim repeats as Integer = 4
        Dim allHomeworks As New List(Of Homework)()

        For i = 0 To repeats - 1
            Dim homework as New Homework

            System.Console.WriteLine("Enter subject " & i + 1)
            homework.Subject = Console.ReadLine()

            System.Console.WriteLine("Enter homework " & i + 1)
            homework.Text = Console.ReadLine()

            System.Console.WriteLine("how many days until " & homework.Subject & "'s homework is due?")
            homework.Deadline = Console.ReadLine()

            ' Add newly created homework to the list
            allHomeworks.Add(homework)
        Next

        ' Sort the items of the list by "Deadline" property of the class 
        allHomeworks.Sort(Function(x, y) x.Deadline.CompareTo(y.Deadline))

        For counter = 0 To allHomeworks.Count - 1
            Console.WriteLine(allHomeworks(counter).Subject & ", " & allHomeworks(counter).Text & ", " & allHomeworks(counter).Deadline & " days")
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

P.S. This is just a quickly written code. You probably should rename some stuff and adjust to your app's logic.

Comment: Or, `myList = myList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Deadline).ToList()`

Comment: Hi @FullyRandom and welcome to stackoverflow!  
I've just updated the answer and added few comments for more clarity.
Please take a look and let me know if the answer fully covers the question.

Comment: @FullyRandom, if that answers to the question, then just click on the checkmark icon nearby to mark it as answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just a few changes to Very Good answer by @JustShadow

My first change is to change the classes fields to `Public Property`. Classes like to keep their data close to the vest in Private fields. They expose their data to the world through Properties. We now have automatic properties by just declaring the variable as a Property. The compiler will write the Get, Set and Private field for us. Of course you can still write it out if you need additional code in the Get or Set.

Also in the class changed Deadline to Date. If the application was expanded where the data was saved and reused a number would not work but a date would.

Next I would not limit the number of homeworks to be added. Just add a Yes/No at the end of the loop.

I changed the For loop to a For Each since we have an IEnumerable. No need to change back to a list. I also simplified the display code with an interpolated string.

```
Public Class Homework
    Public Property Subject As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Deadline As Date
End Class
Sub Main()
    Dim allHomeworks As New List(Of Homework)()
    Do
        Dim h As New Homework
        Console.WriteLine("Enter subject ")
        h.Subject = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter description ")
        h.Description = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Date Due ")
        h.Deadline = CDate(Console.ReadLine())
        ' Add newly created homework to the list
        allHomeworks.Add(h)
        Console.WriteLine("Are you finished? Yes/No")
        If Console.ReadLine.ToLower = "yes" Then Exit Do
    Loop
    Dim sorted = allHomeworks.OrderBy(Function(x) x.Deadline)
    For Each h As Homework In sorted
        Console.WriteLine($"Date Due: {h.Deadline}, Subject: {h.Subject}, Description: {h.Description}")
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```